# Is there a way to link already existing entries in a mysql instead of creating a new one?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am coding a system in which users can tag articles with already existing tags or by creating new ones. But I want to prevent that there are duplicate entries in my "tag-table". 
Instead of creating a new one, hibernate should just link an existing one (if there is already an entry existing).

-> One article should be capable of having zero or more tags
-> One Tag can be assigned to one or more arcticles

So my question:

**Is there a way to link already existing entries in a mysql instead of creating a new one (with hibernate)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide your problem in 2 subtasks.
1. creating/searching tags in your db.
2. storing tags related to any article.

1. you can provide user access to find a tag and if not found then create it.
2. when user want to attach tags to any article, provide him a list of existing tags, and based on user selection you can create their entry in relation table.

This way you will have a manageable list of tags, no duplication and easily list article based on tags.